# How to route React web app to different link from node Js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes, backend

Wheneven I load the page the React app through nodeJs it loads at localhost:5000 but I want that the React app should load through different link like:

```
http://localhost:5000/api
```

The backend code of server.js is as follows:

```
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
    );
    next();
  });

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client", "build")));

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    
    res.sendFile(npath.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });



if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  //static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
  

  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

The above code loads at localhost:5000 but it should load at localhost:5000/api.

Answer (score 0):

Serve your `react` app on the correct location, use `/api` instead of `/` .

```
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
    );
    next();
  });

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/client", "build")));

  // it's now '/api' instead of '/'
  app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    
    res.sendFile(npath.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
```

It's also handy, to add a fallback location for whenever someone lands on `http://localhost:5000` to be redirected to `http://localhost:5000/api`

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/api')
})
```

I am not quiet sure why you are serving the same files twice, when it is production?